# How can I make my email code work PHP?

Tags: php, email

Hey this code is suppose to add an error message when an input was not typed on the email form and its suppose to remove the error message when you finally input the code. I have 2 of them working with the following code:

```
//Generate a unique code
function getUniqueCode($length = "")
{   
$code = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
if ($length != "") return substr($code, 0, $length);
else return $code;
} 

//Generate an activation key
function generateActivationToken($gen = null)
{
do
{
    $gen = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), false));
}
while(validateActivationToken($gen));
return $gen;
}
```

and this code:

```
//Checks if an email is valid
function isValidEmail($email)
{
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

I have made my own code which puts the error messages when there are no inputs on the email form but when I input something right on the email form it does not take the error messages out of the error message box. Here is the code:

```
//Checks if a name is valid
function isValidName($name)
{
if (filter_var($name, MAIL_NAME_ERROR)) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

So to summarize all 5 are working when there is no input like this:

> - Please enter your full name
> - Please enter a valid email address
> - Please enter your telephone number
> - Please enter your password
> - Failed security question

But only my security and email are working when I input my email address and security code like this:

> - Please enter your full name
> - Please enter your telephone number
> - Please enter your password

The name, telephone and password are not working right they only work by showing the code but they do not remove the code when I input the right information.

How can I fix my code so that all 3 will go away 1 by 1?

Comment: `MAIL_NAME_ERROR` ? That's not an existing filter name. All valid filter names can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 0):

To make your own callback you can't just pass the constant `MAIL_NAME_ERROR`. If you want to pass your own function you have to do something like:

```
function mail_name_error(){
  //do your thing here
}
function isValidName($name){
  if(filter_var($name, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => 'mail_name_error'))){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

See the `options` section at http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php .

Comment: Its not working you can check out the page at http://blanky-store.net/access/new_reg_e.php

Comment: Maybe you should just download the PHPglue Library at http://www.PHPglue.com . Review the Documentation and Click the `Downloads` tab. It automatically tests to see if your field is empty, by default. Actually, it will generate your HTML and handle your Sticky Form, both Client and Server Side. You will have to make an email regular expression though. Here's one for you: `'/^.{1,62}@.{1,62}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/'`. It should go in the `errorDiv()` method. You may never have to write complex code to handle your Stick Forms again. Of course, I wrote it!